# How to change my UID back in passwd file?

Tags: passwd-file

My OS is Ubuntu 12.10, and my account is called `acgtyrant`, and its `UID` is `1000`. For the need of researching, I changed my `UID` from `1000` to `1010` in `/etc/passwd`, and then I found my files' master changed to a `number:1000`, which prove my suppose. But when I try to change my UID back, I found I can't edit the passwd file any more! Because when I try to run `sudo vim /etc/passwd`, the Bash told me `sudo: unknown uid 1000: who are you?`.

So how to solve it? Acctually I am a chinese student, so forgive my poor English please.

Comment: I haven't got a LiveCD to hand to test this - but suggest that you boot from a LiveCD and choose to 'test Ubuntu' rather than install it. Then open a terminal and edit the passwd file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press shift during boot then select recovery and drop to a root shell.

Now mount the file system read-write

```
mount -o rw,remount /
```

So far you are following the instructions on how to reset your password from [here](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword)

Finally don't change your password but simply edit the file

```
vipw
```

To edit `/etc/passwd` or `vipw -s` to edit `/etc/shadow`

Similarly use `vigr` to edit `/etc/group` and `vigr -s` to edit `/etc/gshadow`

Standard editors such as **nano** and **vim** do not check the file structure before saving so may make problems worse.

reboot and all should be OK

Comment: Cautionary note: use `vipw` on a live system. For the recovery system this method may be just alright. Use `vigr` for the `group` file. Use the option `-s` to edit the respective shadow files.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Thanks for pointing this out.  I was not aware of the vipw command but just looked it up.  Its safer.

Comment: @acgtyrant  If this solved your problem please accept the answer.  It makes it easier for others with a similar problem to find.  It also doesn't hurt my reputation score :-D.

Comment: @Warren Hill As your wish.

Comment: Thanks a lot! After booting in safe mode, I was simply able to edit /etc/passwd again with plain ol' `vi`, which is what caused this problem in the first place :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try something like this:

```
usermod -u UID_number username
```

Comment: I have solved it already, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

two things:
have a "backup" user

already have a root password setup `$ sudo passwd root`

login with backup user account, then.

```
su
```

now as root, `nano /etc/passwd`
change your uid and gid back to original, most likely `1000:1000`